# Android Share Intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent, share

How can implement an intent for sharing some text in a dialog like this ?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to send those intents or receive them?

Comment: I copied the title of this question into a search engine. Now, guess what I found? -1 for no research effort.

Comment: google is your friend  http://androidforums.com/application-development/98031-share-intent.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(filePath));
try
{
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sending File..."));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There u are:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, YOUR_TEXT_TO_SEND);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use my library [Android Intents](https://github.com/d-tarasov/android-intents). See demo app for details