# Integrating my app with long tap

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am using Monodroid (with Visual Studio 2010) to develop Android apps. Can anyone please guide me how can I integrate my app with long tap i.e. when user presses long tap, my app gets visible in the list so that it can share link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to get your app to show up when someone presses Share in a different app, for example if someone is sharing a picture or link. If so, the android documentation found here: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html explains how to tell Android to add you to that list.
If you are trying to trigger a share event from your own app, look at this SO post: [Android Share Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517545/android-share-intent)