# Android change the text in a "Share" menu

Tags: android

Following the instructions here: [Android Share Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517545/android-share-intent), I have noticed that the text that shows up in the share menu is @string/app_name. Is there a way to make it show some other text without changing the app_name? Either in xml or java, if possible.

Comment: Are you referring to where *your app* shows up in a chooser via `ACTION_SEND`? Or are you *invoking* `startActivity()` on an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`?

Comment: are you saying about app name in actionbar

Comment: I'm talking about after you click the "share" icon (like from the image gallery) the "Share picture via" menu shows, and the text for each entry is the app_name, such as here: http://eggie5.com/8-hook-share-picture-via-menu-android. So if I want my app to show up there, the text that is presented is the app_name, and I would like to change that text without changing my app name.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I forgot to tag you in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if I want my app to show up there, the text that is presented is the app_name, and I would like to change that text without changing my app name.

Add `android:label` to the `<intent-filter>` where your activity is saying that it supports `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Just wondering: is there a way to do it in Java?

Comment: @MrGibbage: I don't think so, sorry.